# OCaml: Adapting recursive function

Tags: list, recursion, tree, ocaml

i've lost all my day in this problem. So, i have a recursive function like that:

```
let rec rewriteTree tree =
      rewriteElement tree c;
      List.iter rewriteTree tree.subtree in
    rewriteTree myTree
```

The function **rewriteElement** returns unit (), so i haven't problems with the function **rewriteTree**. But, i made changes in my code and the function **rewriteElement** now returns a boolean, and i need that it returns a boolean list, with all booleans of all nodes of the tree. What's the best way to do that? I've tried with List.map, but the compiler throws that the function returns (boolean list list). Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to achieve with this function instead? I.e. a sample input and output

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's really hard to explain this. The focusing of the question is about the type of return.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
let rec rewriteTree tree =
  rewriteElement tree c ::
    List.concat (List.map rewriteTree tree.subtree) in
rewriteTree myTree
```

Comment: `List.concat` and `List.flatten` are synonyms.